# Expression symbol of Except

Tags: logic

what is the expression symbol of this following propositional logic ?

- Big peoples eat much except i am hungry.

i've read that A except B is usually translated to A V B and sometimes to A → ¬B and still can not figured out how to translate the propositional above.

Answer (score 1):

"except" just means ^ (AND), with a connotation in the English language that the following statement will somehow be contrary to the preceding statement (connotations do not exist in logic).

So given A = "A person is big", B = "A person eats much", C = "I am hungry", then the sentence would be `(A → B)^C.`

Comment: how do you intepret that sentence ? because i interpret it as i  eat much if i am hungry.

Comment: They're two unrelated statements. On one hand, I am hungry. On the other hand, it is true that big people eat more. There's no logical connection between them with the information you gave.

Comment: i understand, so i intepret it wrong and out of the context of the sentence. thus, except is translated as conjunction because the two premises have no corelation.  another case : - " i eat less except i am hungry " can i put it as A → ¬B ?

Comment: I suspect you are confusing two english words, "except" and "unless". In logic, "except" means ^ (and), and "unless" means → ¬ (if not). "A person eats less unless he is hungry" is translated as ¬A → ¬B, according to the definitions of A and B we have given here.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Each of the following are equivalent:

$A$ is true except if $B$ is true

$[B\implies \neg A]\land [\neg B \implies A]$

$A\iff \neg B$

$A\veebar B\space\space$(Exclusive OR)